# Как сделать что бы флекс элементы имели разную высоту и вставали друг под другом?

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/robmxp

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  ;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы `FLEX` элементы имели вертикальное расстояние между собой ровно в `10px`, а не подстраивались под соседний элемент как на примере.

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 варианта:

Либо использовать `flex-flow: column wrap;` колонки с возможностью переноса блоков. **При этом важно указать ограничение обертки по высоте.**

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.item {
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

И **второй вариант** использовать [masonry сетку](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

```js
$('.items').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  percentPosition: true,
  gutter: 10
});
```

```css
.items {}

.item {
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Флекс контейнеру необходимо добавить направление расположения внутренних флекс элементов: 
`flex-direction: column;`.
Чтобы увидеть соседнюю колонку нужно ограничить высоту флекс контейнера, например `max-height: 300px;`.

Запустите пример кода из этого ответа и сами всё увидите. Вертикальное расстояние ровно в 10px, как и требовалось.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.item {
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  ;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```